# I can't fetch from external API in production

Tags: reactjs, nginx, axios, ubuntu-18.04, dev-to-production

I want to fetch some info but when I try to implement this to server (Ubuntu 18.04) with Nginx I can't fetch...

- Put certificate to enable HTTPS to my domain.
- Create a .env with a variable that contains the complete url to API (Because Im using a proxy in development)
- Put some headers to the petition
- Try to change the config in nginx

But nothing... my application only works running in localhost

```
axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL) ...
```

The console of the browser (Safari):

Origin https://mysubdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mysubdomain.com due to access control checks.

Failed to load resource: Origin https://mysubdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not expert in nginx but this works!

I edit my site file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite like this:

```
location /anyAppLocation/ {

  proxy_method GET;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_pass https://api.site.com;
  proxy_redirect default;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Server needs to return below header value

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

which means anyone can connect to API.

**Work Around**

Go to chrome folder.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="<Some directory name to store temporary chrome data>" --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Ok, let me check that